# ConcurrentModificationException when using Iterator

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to iterate an ArrayList with the Iterator. The problem is that I get the `ConcurrentModificationException`. I have checked a lot of questions like this. All said that the exception occurs when you modify an `ArrayList` while iterating through it. But I think that my problem is a little bit different because I'm not modifying the `ArrayList` even with the `Iterator` methods.

```
        Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente(16096,"Alberto1","pass",1500.0,false);

    ArrayList<Cliente> miLista = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    Iterator<Cliente> miIterador = miLista.iterator();

    miLista.add(cliente1);

    System.out.println(miLista.get(0).nombre); //This displays "Alberto1"
    System.out.println(miIterador.hasNext()); //This displays 'true'
    miIterador.next(); //Here I get the exception
```

I don't know how to solve it. It could be a silly question because actually i'm beginner but I got stuck here.

Thank you.

--Well can't even answer my own question so I edit the question with the answer:

Thank you very much to all of you! You all give me the right answer :D Sorry for the silly question by the way :P

**SOLVED**

Comment: Reorder  `Iterator<Cliente> miIterador = miLista.iterator();` and `miLista.add(cliente1);`

Comment: Great! It was that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is the culprit. You can't modify a list after getting a iterator on it in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods.

```
miLista.add(cliente1);
```

> The iterators returned by ArrayList class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 3):

> " But I think that my problem is a little bit different because I'm
>   not modifying the ArrayList even with the Iterator methods."

But you are modifying the list by adding an element :)

```
    ArrayList<Cliente> miLista = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    Iterator<Cliente> miIterador = miLista.iterator();

    miLista.add(cliente1); 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the problematic line, you are morfing arraylist by adding object to it. Iterator is made on real array list so it throw exception as fail-fast style.

```
miLista.add(cliente1);
```

This is piece of code from arrayList class
it is fired when you invoke getNext on iterator.

```
 final void checkForComodification() {
            if (modCount != expectedModCount)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying list *after* you produce the `Iterator`. Just swap lines

```
Iterator<Cliente> miIterador = miLista.iterator();

miLista.add(cliente1);
```

and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use a ListIterator instead and rewind the iterator after you insert the new Client

```
    Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente(16096,"Alberto1","pass",1500.0,false);

    ArrayList<Cliente> miLista = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    ListIterator<Cliente> miIterador = miLista.listIterator();

    miIterador.add(cliente1);
    miIterador.previous();

    System.out.println(miLista.get(0).getHombre()); //This displays "Alberto1" << notice you're not using the iterator here
    System.out.println(miIterador.hasNext()); //This displays 'true'
    System.out.println(miIterador.next().getHombre()); //This displays "Albert1" again
```